# add file to $_FILES array by reading remote file

Tags: php, curl, wordpress

I'm pretty new to php and we're trying to write a plugin for wordpress.  We have a server with images on it and we'd like to have the plugin have a list of images to download from the server.  It then needs to go through that list and read each image from the server into the $_FILES variable that we can then pass to the wordpress media_handle_upload function.

I've been able to read a remote file with the following code.  But I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
$url = 'http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/2010Redesign/images/LangugeHomePages/PHP.png';

$img = curl_init();
curl_setopt($img, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($img, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($img, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($img, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$file = curl_exec($img);
curl_close($img);


$file_array = explode("\n\r", $file, 2);
$header_array = explode("\n", $file_array[0]);
foreach($header_array as $header_value) {
  $header_pieces = explode(':', $header_value);
  if(count($header_pieces) == 2) {
    $headers[$header_pieces[0]] = trim($header_pieces[1]);
  }
}
header('Content-type: ' . $headers['Content-Type']);
header('Content-Disposition: ' . $headers['Content-Disposition']);


$imgFile = substr($file_array[1], 1);
echo $imgFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Lookup table

Create images name list or image file path(link) list as json,xml or txt format. so it will act like as lookup table. it can be parse easily (just like RSS feed customization). call the json or xml file and get the data in the form of array. now you can process it easily

Comment: That was my plan for getting the data from my server to php.  I'm asking once I download an image, how do I add it and all of it's information to the global $_FILES variable that the wordpress function uses?

Comment: if download is automatic(catch), it is difficult to keep the all info in to $_FILES. better make an array and insert data in to it. you can use "for each" setup for assigning data one by one and pass to $_FILES.

Comment: i will try to help you

Comment: use imagecreatefromstring(), if your project based on sampling or web fetcher.

Comment: My understanding is that the $_FILES variable is auto populated with lots of information on the file that was uploaded and where it was temporarily saved.  So, I'm not sure how to populate that with the information from the file I download and make sure it's set up properly.  I appreciate your willingness to help, but I really need to see some code... I just don't have enough experience with php to take the concept and run with it without seeing any example code.  Thanks.